# Spring TransactionTemplate with nested calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I've a application with a complex transaction scenario.

I've a task that do many transactions. I try to simplify it to show you the concept:

I've a main task that open a transaction for every appointment readed from the db:

```
@Component
public class MainTask {

@Inject
TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * ?")
public void execute() { 

List<Long> appointments = new ArrayList<Long>();

transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
            try {                   
                appointments= communicationClass.loadAppointments();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("", e);
                status.setRollbackOnly();
            }
            return null;
        });

appointmens.parallelStream().forEach(id -> {
            transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
                try {

                    communicationClass.evaluateSms(id);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("", e);
                    status.setRollbackOnly();
                }
                return null;
            });
```

This is the CommunicationClass:

```
@Component
public class CommunicationClass{

         @PersistenceContext
         EntityManager entityManager;

  public List<Long> loadAppointments() {
           //CALL A SERVICE TO GET THE LIST OF APPOINTMENTS
           return appointmentService.loadAppointments();
  }


      public void evaluateSms(long idAppuntamento) {
         boolean orarioSms = templateServiceImpl.canInviaSms(template, appuntamento);

        //REMOTE CALL
        boolean esitoInvio = inviaSmsGateway(appuntamento, sms, template);
                if (esitoInvio == false)
                    throw new RuntimeException("Rollback of the entire transaction");
 }
```

This is the TemplateServiceImpl class used before:

```
@Service
@Transactional
 public class TemplateServiceImpl {

 public boolean canInviaSms(Template template, IHasComunicazioni oggetto) {
    //DO SOMETHING WITH OBJECTS RECEIVED
}
```

My questions are:

1. The transaction opened from the transactionTemplate is preserved also when there is a call to communicationClass and later to the service (annotated with @Transactional)?
2. The RuntimeException thrown in evaluateSms() should rollback the entire transaction opened inside the for(), right?
3. if is thrown an exception inside the method canInviaSms() of TemplateServiceImpl is rolledback the entire transaction?

Thanks

Comment: There is no 1 transaction there is 1 for loading and one for each id that is processed. There is no single transaction just many small ones. So basically the answer to all your questions would be no in this case. Because if you have 100 ids, you get 101 transactions (1 for read 100 for writes). Now if after 94 writes the thing crashes only the one that is problematic will not be committed everything else will be in the database.

Comment: I mean, if the transaction opened inside the for() is preserved in nested calls. It's ok in my case that if I've 100 id, only the problematic transaction is not persisted and all others yes. My question is: the "small" transaction opened inside the for() method are preserved also if there are calls to others class annotated with @Service or @Transactional?

Comment: Everything that is under the `execute` method is transactional regardless how many calls that are of how many methods are chained...